# caching support in Restler?

Tags: php, api, caching, rest, restler

I wanted to to implement a restful web service and came across Restler 2.0.

What i wanted to know is whether Restler provides any caching support(server side/client side) .
I understand that the main purpose of Restler is to allow you a very easy way to expose your resources in a Rest API format. However, wanted to know whether caching support is provided as of now or will be added into the framework anytime soon

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

---

**Update**: Restler 3 is released with Caching Support and available [here](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/tree/v3)!

---

Restler 2 does not have any caching support, but Restler 3 will be supporting client side caching and also some mechanisms to enable server side caching.

You can follow the roadmap [here](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/wiki/Restler-3-Status-Report), and suggest the features [here](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/22)